# How to fix Encoding error that I get after enabling the XML Transformation in Azure Release pipeline

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, config

I am trying to merge different .config file to Web.config depending on which environment the Release is deployed.
But, when I enable the XML Transformation in IIS web app deploy task, I get the below mentioned encoding error.
I updated all the .config file with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` , but that did not help.
Can you please guide what's causing this and how to resolve this ?

Logs below :

```
2022-05-06T12:55:41.5288177Z ##[section]Starting: Gal Service Web App Deploy
2022-05-06T12:55:41.5552489Z ==============================================================================
2022-05-06T12:55:41.5552769Z Task         : IIS web app deploy
2022-05-06T12:55:41.5552986Z Description  : Deploy a website or web application using Web Deploy
2022-05-06T12:55:41.5553202Z Version      : 0.198.0
2022-05-06T12:55:41.5553357Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-05-06T12:55:41.5553630Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group
2022-05-06T12:55:41.5553987Z ==============================================================================
2022-05-06T12:55:42.0686645Z [command]C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.198.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-webdeployment-common\7zip\7zip\7z.exe x -oC:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_7556076901452693 C:\azagent\A1\_work\r5\a\_Gal\dropGalservice\GalPublish.zip
2022-05-06T12:55:42.1085817Z 
2022-05-06T12:55:42.1086508Z 7-Zip [64] 16.00 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-10
2022-05-06T12:55:42.1086747Z 
2022-05-06T12:55:42.1087046Z Scanning the drive for archives:
2022-05-06T12:55:42.1087266Z 1 file, 24101543 bytes (23 MiB)
2022-05-06T12:55:42.1087372Z 
2022-05-06T12:55:42.1087623Z Extracting archive: C:\azagent\A1\_work\r5\a\_Gal\dropGalservice\GalPublish.zip
2022-05-06T12:55:42.7166781Z --
2022-05-06T12:55:42.7167278Z Path = C:\azagent\A1\_work\r5\a\_Gal\dropGalservice\GalPublish.zip
2022-05-06T12:55:42.7168109Z Type = zip
2022-05-06T12:55:42.7168503Z Physical Size = 24101543
2022-05-06T12:55:42.7168682Z 
2022-05-06T12:55:42.7185541Z Everything is Ok
2022-05-06T12:55:42.7185833Z 
2022-05-06T12:55:42.7186125Z Folders: 3
2022-05-06T12:55:42.7186357Z Files: 123
2022-05-06T12:55:42.7186630Z Size:       58978206
2022-05-06T12:55:42.7186941Z Compressed: 24101543
2022-05-06T12:55:43.4658838Z [command]C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.198.0\ctt\ctt.exe s:C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_7556076901452693\Web.config t:C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_7556076901452693\Web.Release.config d:C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_7556076901452693\Web.config pw i verbose
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6253468Z System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6255179Z    at Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlTransformationLogger.ConvertUriToFileName(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6255638Z    at Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlTransformationLogger.LogWarning(XmlNode referenceNode, String message, Object[] messageArgs)
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6256021Z    at Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.Transform.ApplyOnAllTargetNodes()
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6256362Z Start tranformation to 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_7556076901452693\Web.config'.
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6256757Z Source file: 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_7556076901452693\Web.config'.
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6257125Z Transform  file: 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_7556076901452693\Web.Release.config'.
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6262845Z Transformation task is using encoding 'System.Text.UTF8Encoding'. Change encoding in source file, or use the 'encoding' parameter if you want to change encoding.
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6263668Z Executing RemoveAttributes (transform line 18, 18)
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6264240Z on /configuration/system.web/compilation
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6264912Z Applying to 'compilation' element (no source line info)
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6265636Z File: , LineNumber: 18, LinePosition: 18, Message: Argument 'debug' did not match any attributes
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6266266Z Done executing RemoveAttributes
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6386070Z ##[error]Error: XML transformation error while transforming C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_7556076901452693\Web.config using C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_7556076901452693\Web.Release.config.
2022-05-06T12:55:43.6471085Z ##[section]Finishing: Gal Service Web App Deploy
```

[image: release pipeline]

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
</system.web>
```

You can try to resolve the error by changing the above transform code to the below code:

```xml
<system.web>
   <compilation targetFramework="4.5" xdt:Transform="Replace">
   </compilation>
</system.web>
```

If you are targetting a different version of the framework, set it to the framework version that is in the web.config.
The issue could also be when the VSBuild task is transforming the web.config file, and then the release pipeline as well. You can see that the VSBuild task not to transform by the following code:

```vhdl
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)" /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False /p:TransformWebConfigEnabled=False'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```